# Rust: Encode a JPEG image into a PNG using image-rs

Tags: image, rust, png, decode, encode

I'm using the `image` ([Link to repo](https://github.com/image-rs/image)) crate in Rust, to encode a GIF image into a PNG with the following code:

```rust
  fn encode_png(&self, img: &DynamicImage) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let file = File::create("icon.png").unwrap();
    let ref mut buff = BufWriter::new(file);
    let encoder = PNGEncoder::new(buff);

    match encoder.encode(&img.to_bytes(), 256, 256, img.color()) {
      Ok(_) => Ok(()),
      Err(err) => Err(Error::new(err.description()))
    }
  }
```

The `img` variable represents a `DynamicImage` which I opened using the `open` method from the same crate.

What happens is, that the programs runs successfuly but the output file is broken.
I wrote the code based on the following docs:
[PNGEncoder | encode](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.4/image/png/struct.PNGEncoder.html#method.encode)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know what the issue with the result is? How does the file compare with a correctly encoded one? Also, are your settings, such as the original file and the image dimensions correct?

Comment: Thanks for asking @SolomonUcko! You helped me figuring out what was the issue when asking if the dimensions are correct!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue with my code above is that I'm giving the wrong image dimensions to the encoder as parameters (256, 256).

I expected the image to be resized to 256x256 but the encoder expects the current image dimensions in order to work as expected.

The following code is running as expected:

```rust
  fn encode_png(&self, img: &DynamicImage) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let file = File::create("icon.png").unwrap();
    let ref mut buff = BufWriter::new(file);
    let encoder = PNGEncoder::new(buff);

    match encoder.encode(&img.to_bytes(), img.dimensions().0, img.dimensions().1, img.color()) {
      Ok(_) => Ok(()),
      Err(err) => Err(Error::new(err.description()))
    }
  }
```

Thanks to [Solomon Ucko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445670/solomon-ucko) for pointing it out in the comments!

As I needed to resize the image and then encode it to a PNG file, I ended up with the following:

```rust
  fn encode_png(&self, img: &DynamicImage) -> Result<(), Error> {
    if img.dimensions().0 != 256 {
      let resized = img.resize_exact(256, 256, FilterType::Gaussian);

      return self.encode_png(&resized);
    }

    let file = File::create("icon.png").unwrap();
    let ref mut buff = BufWriter::new(file);
    let encoder = PNGEncoder::new(buff);

    match encoder.encode(&img.to_bytes(), img.dimensions().0, img.dimensions().1, img.color()) {
      Ok(_) => Ok(()),
      Err(err) => Err(Error::new(err.description()))
    }
  }
```